# Responsive Div Content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**Goal**:  I'm trying to style content to be responsive to the dimensions of it's parent div.

**Required Behavior**

- Depending on the div container the content would react to it and scale appropriately.
- I need content to always be centered.
- Move a container up when there's enough room to fit 2 containers horizontally (example JsFiddle: card-container2 shows the image and card info side by side but the button is still centered.)

**Conditions I must meet**:

- I am not allowed to use any media Queries.
- I am not allowed to use any JavaScript
- It must ALL be done in html and CSS.

```css
.product-image-area {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
max-width: 180px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz840wh2/2/)

EDIT:
Due to the complexity of my question I shall illustrate this monster of a task I've been given:

Image: http://i63.photobucket.com/albums/h123/Damian6969/Stack_EXample_zpsmskwkba0.png

So my html code in the black rectangle (let's call this the "inner" container) will always be the same.

This inner container will always have a width of 100% and height of 100%.

The orange container (the "outer" container) will change in dimensions.

I need my inner container be responsive.

...I don't know if I can simplify this anymore guys. Another example is responsive code in general. But instead of a viewport, you have only an outer div.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please reduce the complexity of your question to one point. As it is, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Also, HTML with a bunch of inline styles will get you groans galore. Please take the time to prepare clean markup by moving styles to the stylesheet, or at least an embedded style tag.

Comment: I hope my edits made my question more clear. Fixed up JsFiddle too. Thanks!

Comment: Much improved, but still too broad. You have a list of requirements but you don't say which single item is tripping you up. Also, don't think "cascade" is the right term here. Do you mean wraps to a new line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an outer container with

```
text-align: center;
```

Then give your inner containers

```
display: inline-block;
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/9hj157tw/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not exactly sure what you're trying to fix, but here's what I did to tune things up:

```
.c-product-card {
    ...
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.card-info {
    ...
    text-align: left;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fz840wh2/3/)**